# Convergence of series with Landau symbols

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

thanks for the replies, I'll give you guys some details.

Fix $q > 1$. Consider now a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ which satisfy

$\Vert X_n \Vert_q = O(f(n)) $ almost surely, where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_q = (\int \vert \cdot \vert^q d\mathbb{P})^{1/q}$.

What I want to show, is that

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{\Vert X_n \Vert_q}{g(n)})^q < \infty$
and thus by Borel-Cantelli $X_n = o(g(n))$ almost surely.

My idea was to write the sum as
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{\Vert X_n \Vert_q}{f(n)})^q (\frac{f(n)}{g(n)})^q =: \sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n)$,

where $h(n) = O( (\frac{f(n)}{g(n)})^q)$. In my case I have $f(n) = \log(n)$ and $g(n) = n^{1/2}$. I'm very insecure whether this approach might work and whether there is a chance to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty h(n) < \infty$ with the assumptions above. So I was wondering, if someone else thought about problems like this and could help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be greater if you'd share your thoughts first. "convert"?

Comment: What is the point of your series? If $f(n)=o(g(n))$ then $X_n= O(f(n))$ almost surely implies $X_n=o(g(n))$ almost surely.

Comment: Well, for $q=2$ we have $\sum \frac{\log^2(n)}{n}$ which diverges so your series diverges for any $q\leq 2$. (For any $q>2$ it's going to converge.)

Comment: How did you show that $\sum \frac{\log^q(n)}{n^{q/2}}$ converges for $q > 2$?

Comment: @reuns Does $\Vert X_n \Vert_q = O(f(n))$ already imply $X_n = O(f(n))$ almost surely?